Reference error on register.ejs "loggedIn" is not defined, but its defined in the index.js file
The index.js file has loggedIn rendered as a variable for the ejs file but it keeps telling me its not defined:


                <ul class="flex items-center p-1 grow justify-end">
                    <li
                        class="text-white duration-150 hover:bg-[#2e3e58] dark:hover:dark:bg-[#202124] py-1 px-2 mx-1 rounded-md">
                        <% if (loggedIn) { %>
                        <a href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
                        <% } else { %>
                        <a href="/users/login">Login or Sign Up</a>
                        <% } %>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img
                            class="sunDisabled cursor-pointer justify-center"
                            src="../images/brightness-high.svg"
                            alt="BrightModeDisabled" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img
                            class="sunEnabled cursor-pointer justify-center"
                            src="../images/brightness-high-fill.svg"
                            alt="BrightModeEnabled" />
                    </li>
                </ul>

and this is the index.js file:
// Imports
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const passport = require("passport");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });

const { pool } = require("../config/dbConfig");
const initializePassport = require("../config/passportConfig");
const { bibleQuery } = require("./bibleQuery");
const { fathersQuery } = require("./fathersQuery");
const { register } = require("./register");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

initializePassport(passport);

// Middleware
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render("../public/views/index", {
            loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated(),
            user: req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user.name : null,
        });
    } else {
        res.render("../public/views/index", { loggedIn: false });
    }
});

app.get("/users/register", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("../public/views/register", { loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated() });
});

app.get("/users/login", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("../public/views/login", { loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated() });
});

bibleQuery(app, pool);
fathersQuery(app, pool);
register(app, pool);

app.get("/users/logout", (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    });
    req.flash("success_msg", "You have logged out");
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post(
    "/users/login",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/users/login",
        failureFlash: true,
    })
);

/**
 * @param {{ isAuthenticated: () => any; }} req
 * @param {{ redirect: (arg0: string) => any; }} res
 * @param {() => void} next
 */
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
    next();
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

Tried restarting my server, updated npm packages, tried 50 times rearranging the code and nothing works still. the index.js file also point out that bcrypt is declared but never read, but that wasn't a problem for me in the past, I haven't touched this code and it worked fine until today.

You should never keep your views in your public folder but instead keep the views folder in the same directory as either your index.js or public directory, if it is not with the index.js you will need to set the views property with app.set('views', '<path>'); , you should also do res.render('viewName') instead of a file path when doing this.
The bcrypt warning is not an issue but as its not being used you can safely remove the line requiring it.
Also can you try using console.log in a script tag so something like: <script>console.log('logged in: <%= locals.loggedIn %>');</script>

In the register.js file, the {loggedIn: loggedIn} variable wasn't declared. issue is fixed
